# Not able to access local variable of a function in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, closures

Below is my sample code.

```
  let myDataObject= await myRepo.getInformation();
  await customerService.createObject(dtoObject, (data: any) => {
            for(let record in myDataObject){
                console.log(record)
            }
        });
```

In the above code **myDataObject** get filled with my repository response.
dtoObject get filled from my other service logic.

I tried to :

1. fix it using declaring a global variable
2. fix it by passing myDataObject to customerService.createObject and returning in the callback

But i want to do it using closures. Is closures the best possible way to fix the above issue?

Comment: Needs more context.  A note that using function closures could cause problems with your async/await code.

Comment: In the example code you give it looks like you are already using closures for that. Note that using a global variable and using a closure means exactly the same thing since a global variable is nothing more than a closure capturing the global scope

Comment: does it help to put bind inside }); ?   like this:    }.bind(this));
in my case it was like    this.myDataObject  ,  after binding, the code inside the callback can reference  this.myDataObject  properly

Comment: "*I tried to fix it*" - please state clearly what does not work first. "*i want to do it using closures*" - the code you posted already does use closures. The `(data: any) => {…}` callback does close over the `let myDataObject` variable that it uses.